# How to use modifier key combinations?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm building a basic text editor, with SFML. For this I need to save with the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

My current solution saves when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, AND produces an 's' in my editor. This extra 's' is not wanted.

This is the code I currently have:

```
//Main loop:

if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
    {
        if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S
            && event.key.control)
        {
            cout << "testing" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
    {
    }
```

In other words: I want TextEntered to be working normally. But if I press CTRL + S, it will disable TextEntered and perform the save. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a real-time key check inside the handler for `TextEntered`. e.g.

```
else if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
{
    if (!sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LControl) &&
        !sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::RControl))
    {
        // handle text event
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else, or nothing
    }
}
```